# What is an event object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Does it exist before an event is triggered or is it created by the event?
For example when a click event is triggered is the click property added to some already existing event object? Or is an object for this event created when the event is triggered?

Comment: An object for the event is created when the event is triggered.

Comment: It's created when an event fires, and passed into your event handler function

Comment: This might help: [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect you are referring to a JavaScript Event ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event ) and not a jQuery Event Object ( https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ ). For the Latter, you could have one before an event is triggered or called.

Comment: @Twisty for either you can create your own event object (js/jquery variant) first  `const event = new Event('name');` and `var event = jQuery.Event("name");`

Comment: @freedomn-m that's wonderful news to me. Thank you!

Comment: @freedomn-m I have done that with jQuery Event Objects; not tried it with plain Object. Thanks for that. I know I will use it in the future at some time.

Comment: @Twisty my bad, I misread which way round you had used them.  Link above creating and triggering events for js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is created when a certain event is fired; you can then use it inside your event handler function.

Here is a compact example with jQuery, as requested:

```js
$("#my-btn").click(e => {
  console.log("Here is the event object:");
  console.log(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="my-btn">Click</button>
<i>Logging the object to the console may be slow as the event object is very large</i>
```

Comment: And is it the same in Jquery?

Comment: @mango33 Yes, pretty much. I have just updated my answer for jQuery